# how to extract points from the string "(1,3),(4,6),(3,6)" using java

Tags: java, string, split

i am unable to extracts only the points to matrix array using java and then assign it to matrix a[6][6]. I am trying to use split, but it is not working the way I want. Does anyone have suggestion?

Comment: post your code and give us some sample inputs and your desired output.

Comment: Please tell us what do you want?

Comment: I would suggest regular expressions

Comment: can i ask how your matrix should look like?

Comment: i need to assign matrix a[1][3]=value1,a[4][6]=value2.....

Comment: complete your matrice with your values, there are many possibilities for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract numbers from your String for example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "(1,3),(4,6),(3,6)";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (mat.find()) {
        list.add(Integer.parseInt(mat.group()));
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

This will gives you a List of int :

```
[1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6]
```

Then you use this value in your array like you want.

**EDIT**

> ...extracts only the points to matrix array using java and then assign
>   it to **matrix a[6][6]**

Your matrix should be in this format :

```
v v v v v v
v v v v v v
v v v v v v
v v v v v v
v v v v v v
v v v v v v
```

So to do that you have to use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "(1,3),(4,6),(3,6)";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

    int[][] a = new int[6][6];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (mat.find()) {
        if(j == 6){
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
        a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(mat.group());
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
}
```

This will give you :

```
[[1, 3, 4, 6, 3, 6], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: you don't have any logic of assigning values to your matrix so you have to give us an example how your matrix should look like @Totanagoudapatil ok

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the point as a pair x,y

so regex will help

```
    String x = "(1,3),(4,6),(3,6)";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)").matcher(x);
    while (m.find()) {
        String[] s = m.group(1).split(",");
        int x1 = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
        int y1 = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
        System.out.println(x1 + " , " + y1);

    }
```

> 1 , 3
>
> 4 , 6
>
> 3 , 6