# Java: String to integer array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a string, which is a list of coordinates, as follows:

```
st = "((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(2,3))"
```

I want this to be converted to an array of coordinates,

```
a[0] = 1,2
a[1] = 2,3
a[2] = 3,4
....
```

and so on.

I can do it in Python, but I want to do it in Java. 
So how can I split the string into array in java??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: `split("),(")` and remove the remaining parenthesis?

Comment: 'split("),(")'  may work, but the first and last element have extra parenthesis with them.

Comment: @MoidShaikh Than replace the first and last paranthesis if it´s not needed here

Comment: [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java) this is different. In my string, there is extra parenthesis. It's a list of coordinates.

Comment: possible relation to http://stackoverflow.com/a/42782917/982161

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done fairly easily with regex, capturing `(\d+,\d+)` and the looping over the matches

```
String st = "((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(2,3))";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d+),(\\d+)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(st);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2));
}
System.out.println(matches);
```

If you genuinely need an array, this can be converted

```
String [] array = matches.toArray(new String[matches.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
    String str="((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(2,3))";
    ArrayList<String> arry=new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int x=0; x<=str.length()-1;x++)
    {
        if (str.charAt(x)!='(' && str.charAt(x)!=')' && str.charAt(x)!=',')
        {
            arry.add(str.substring(x, x+3));
            x=x+2;
        }
    }

    for (String valInArry: arry)
    {
        System.out.println(valInArry);
    }
```

If you don't want to use Pattern-Matcher;

Answer (score 0):

This should be it:

```
String st = "((1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(2,3))";
String[] array = st.substring(2, st.length() - 2).split("\\),\\(");
```